# Arc with nodes evenly distributed

Tags: tikz-pgf, plot

Im using the beamer template for a presentation.
I'd like to have a coordiante system where there is a smooth arc from the upper left to the lower right as a pareto front. On this arc, I want to have nodes evenly distributed. Currently, I have a foreach to get the nodes on a line and draw the arc behind it? How can I get the nodes exactly onto that arc?
I also need those nodes to appear after each other.

This is what I have so far.

```latex
    \begin{tikzpicture}[anchor=mid west, mark size=+4pt, ball color=black!80]
        % \draw [lightgray, thin] (0,0) grid (6,6);

        \pause
        \draw [latex-latex,thick] (0,6) 
            -- (0,0) node[rotate=90, midway, above, align=center] {Performance} 
            -- (6,0) node[           midway, below, align=center] {Ease of Resuasability};

        \onslide<7->{\draw [draw=black!60] (0.5,5.5) to[out=-20, in=110] (5.5,0.5);}

        \pause
        \foreach \impl[count=\cnt] in {Generic C, Field Specific C, CPU Specific, Hand Tuned Assembly} {
            \draw[mark options={fill=red}]
                plot[mark=ball] coordinates {(6.5-\cnt*1.4, 1.4*\cnt-0.5)} node[fill=white,xshift=.5em] {\impl};
            \pause
        }


        \pause
        \node [single arrow, rotate=45, fill=white, draw=blue] at (4,4) {\quad\quad\quad};

        \onslide<1-> %% workaround to have the footline
    \end{tikzpicture}
```

the result is:
[image: Graph]

I've tried to use the 'plot' with

```latex
\draw[color=blue] plot[smooth, tension=1, mark=ball, mark indices={1,2}] coordinates {(0.5, 5.5) (6, 4) (9.5, 0.5)};
```

which gives me a nice arc, but I don't want to specify all other nodes on this graph, let alone the coordinates. Also I don't know where to add the `\pause`es.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could place coordinates along the path via `pos`.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}[t]
\frametitle{Arc with coordinates}
\begin{tikzpicture}[anchor=mid west, mark size=+4pt, ball color=black!80]
    % \draw [lightgray, thin] (0,0) grid (6,6);

    \pause
    \draw [latex-latex,thick] (0,6) 
        -- (0,0) node[rotate=90, midway, above, align=center] {Performance} 
        -- (6,0) node[           midway, below, align=center] {Ease of Resuasability};

    \draw [draw=black!60] (0.5,5.5) to[out=-20, in=110] 
        coordinate[pos=1/5] (p-1) coordinate[pos=2/5] (p-2)
        coordinate[pos=3/5] (p-3) coordinate[pos=4/5] (p-4)
    (5.5,0.5);
    \pause 
    \foreach \impl[count=\cnt] in {Generic C, Field Specific C, CPU Specific, Hand Tuned Assembly} {
       \draw[mark options={fill=red}]
           plot[mark=ball] coordinates {(p-\cnt)} node[right=.5em] {\impl};
        \pause   
    }

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{frame}    
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

- If you would provide MWE, that it would be much easier to help you ...
- It also is not entirely clear, how image elements shows up
- See, if the following solution is what you after )I rewrote you code fragments from scratch ...)

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{tikz} 
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta,
                backgrounds,
                shapes.arrows}
                

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}[fragile] % needed because of dot style definition
\frametitle{Frame title}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[
dot/.style = {circle, ball color=blue!80,
              label=right:#1
              },
lbl/.style = {auto=right, sloped},
 SA/.style = {single arrow, draw=blue, thick,
              minimum height=6em,
              anchor=tail, rotate=45}
                        ]
\draw [Latex-Latex,thick] 
    (0,6) -- node[lbl] {Performance}            (0,0)
          -- node[lbl] {Ease of Resuasability}  (6,0);
\foreach \impl [count=\cnt,
                count=\sld from 2] in  {Generic C, 
                                 Field Specific C,
                                 CPU Specific,
                                 Hand Tuned Assembly}
{
\onslide<\sld->{
    \node[dot=\impl] at (\cnt*90/5:5) {};
                }
}

\scoped[on background layer]
{
\onslide<6->{\draw[semithick]   (10:5)  arc(10:80:5);}
\onslide<7->{\node [SA] at (45:5.5) {};}
}
   \end{tikzpicture}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

first slide:

[image]

third slide:

[image]

before last slide:

[image]
last slide:

[image]